# QObject error with macro and include

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

I want to use signal and slot in my program and for this I am told Ineed to add Q_OBJECT as below.

Well I have a class:

```
class A
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    A();
};
```

This gives an error which says 'Q_OBJECT does not name a type'. If I than add #include  It give the error 'undefined reference to vtable of A'

So what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Q_OBJECT` macro is meant for subclasses of a `QObject` (or other subclasses). It is also required if you want your class to use signals and slots.

```
class A 
    : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

 public:
    A(QObject *parent = 0);
};
```

---

[Q_OBJECT](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT)

> The Q_OBJECT macro must appear in the private section of a class
>   definition that declares its own signals and slots or that uses other
>   services provided by Qt's meta-object system.
>   ...
>   **Note:**
>    This macro requires the class to be a subclass of QObject. ...

Comment: Ok. But for some reason I cannot get it work. I forgot that my class inherits from QGraphicsItem and when I add Qobject as superclass or not it keeps given the vtable error.

Comment: Never mind, it's solved suddenly. I probably needed to rebuild all.